# Windows SBS 2008 to Windows Server 2012 migration

Tags: windows, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013

I am in the process of upgrading my Windows SBS 2008 server running Exchange, Active Directory and as a File server to Windows Server 2012 essentials. Now I know that Windows Server 2012 essentials does not have exchange, thus I was looking to migrate the Active directory and the file server to Windows Server 2012 essentials, Then I would have a separate Virtual machine running Windows server 2012 standard with Exchange 2013. Now my question is, what should I do first? Migrate the AD and File server to Windows 2012 essentials and then after the migration is finished, I create a local move of the mailboxes from SBS 2008 to Windows Server 2012 standard running exchange 2013? or should this be the other way round?

Comment: You can't have Exchange without AD so you'll need AD first. As for the rest, it's up to you.

Comment: Ok I know that, but should I first move the exchange out of the SBS or should I leave the exchange on the SBS, and move out the AD and file server first and when these are moved to the 2012 essentials, I install another machine with server 2012 w/ exchange 2013 and migrate the exchange then ?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has published information on [migrating from SBS 2008 to Essentials 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200141.aspx) and [migrating from previous version of Windows to Essentials 2012 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408633.aspx). However, it does not contain information on migrating Exchange. For that, refer to Microsoft's [guide for migration from SBS 2008 to SBS 2011](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19219). While this guide doesn't exactly fit your particular situation, it will contain useful information that you can adapt as needed. You may also want to use the [Exchange Server Deployment Assistant](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/jj657516.aspx).

Note the following:

- You must install Essentials in migration mode in order to join it to the existing domain. (See [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730348.aspx).)
- Then you can add the 2012 Standard server, install Exchange, and migrate from the existing Exchange 2007 server to the new server.
- The source SBS 2008 server must be removed from the domain within 21 days of beginning the migration.
- Be aware that there may be group policy settings which will no longer be applicable in the new network, or that may conflict with group policy objects created by Essentials.

Caveat: I have not done this particular scenario, but I've done many SBS-SBS migrations and SBS-Standard server migrations.

Comment: Didn't realize I was responding to an old post. Oh well, hopefully someone finds it useful.